# Unable to register mcast address in c++

Tags: c++, vmware, cisco

i was working for a routing algo protocol in c++ on centos. centos was running on vmware .. 
i was able to register mcast address 224.0.0.9 when my interfaces card are connected in bridge mode in vmware. but as i connected my centos with cisco router using gns3 cloud i got errors

so overall topolgoy is like

cenots++bridgemode-----bridgemode+centos //able to add into group

centos+--vmnet1-----------+vmnet1(gns3cloud---cisco router)  //unable to add into group

```
h=gethostbyname("224.0.0.9");
if(h==NULL) {
     cout << "unknown group address"<<endl; 
  exit(1);
}
```

if
     memcpy((char *) &mcastAddr.sin_addr.s_addr,h->h_addr_list[0],h->h_length);

```
mreq.imr_multiaddr.s_addr=mcastAddr.sin_addr.s_addr;   //
mreq.imr_interface.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);

int mc = setsockopt(soc,IPPROTO_IP,IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP,(void *) &mreq, sizeof(mreq));
if(mc<0) {
 cout <<"unable to join MCAST GROUP"<<endl;
 printf("ERROR: %s\n", strerror(errno));
exit(1);
```

}

errno returns.
ERROR: No such device

ps# there is only one interface eth0 using which m able to ping cisco router

Any pointer is welcomed

Thanks